# How to highlight the differences between two strings in Python?

Tags: python, string, colors, nlp, difference

I want to highlight the differences between two strings in a colour using Python code.

Example 1:

```
sentence1 = "I'm enjoying the summer breeze on the beach while I do some pilates."
sentence2 = "I am enjoying the summer breeze on the beach while I am doing some pilates."
```

Expected result (the part marked by asterisks should be in red):

```
 I *am* enjoying the summer breeze on the beach while I *am doing* some pilates.
```

Example 2:

```
sentence1: "My favourite season is Autumn while my sister's favourite season is Winter."
sentence2: "My favourite season is Autumn, while my sister's favourite season is Winter."
```

Expected result (the comma is different):

```
"My favourite season is Autumn*,* while my sister's favourite season is Winter."
```

I tried this:

```py
sentence1 = "I'm enjoying the summer breeze on the beach while I do some pilates."
sentence2 = "I'm enjoying the summer breeze on the beach while I am doing some pilates."

# Split the sentences into words
words1 = sentence1.split()
words2 = sentence2.split()

# Find the index where the sentences differ
index_of_difference = next((i for i, (word1, word2) in enumerate(zip(words1, words2)) if word1 != word2), None)

# Highlight differing part "am doing" in red
highlighted_words = []
for i, (word1, word2) in enumerate(zip(words1, words2)):
    if i == index_of_difference:
        highlighted_words.append('\033[91m' + word2 + '\033[0m')
    else:
        highlighted_words.append(word2)

highlighted_sentence = ' '.join(highlighted_words)
print(highlighted_sentence)
```

And I got this:

```
I'm enjoying the summer breeze on the beach while I *am* doing some
```

Instead of this:

```
I'm enjoying the summer breeze on the beach while I *am doing* some pilates.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Ok but how do I solve this?  @user19077881

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the main issue with your code was with getting the indexes of the differences. Here is a solution that makes use of the built-in Python [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) library:

```py
from difflib import Differ

# Return string with the escape sequences at specific indexes to highlight
def highlight_string_at_idxs(string, indexes):
    # hl = "\x1b[38;5;160m"  # 8-bit
    hl = "\x1b[91m"
    reset = "\x1b[0m"
    words_with_hl = []
    for string_idx, word in enumerate(string.split(" ")):
        if string_idx in indexes:
            words_with_hl.append(hl + word + reset)
        else:
            words_with_hl.append(word)
    return " ".join(words_with_hl)

# Return indexes of the additions to s2 compared to s1
def get_indexes_of_additions(s1, s2):
    diffs = list(Differ().compare(s1.split(" "), s2.split(" ")))
    indexes = []
    adj_idx = 0  # Adjust index to compensate for removed words
    for diff_idx, diff in enumerate(diffs):
        if diff[:1] == "+":
            indexes.append(diff_idx - adj_idx)
        elif diff[:1] == "-":
            adj_idx += 1
    return indexes

sentence1 = "I'm enjoying the summer breeze on the beach while I do some pilates."
sentence2 = "I am enjoying the summer breeze on the beach while I am doing some pilates."
addition_idxs = get_indexes_of_additions(sentence1, sentence2)
hl_sentence2 = highlight_string_at_idxs(sentence2, addition_idxs)
print(hl_sentence2)
```

#### Output

```
*I am* enjoying the summer breeze on the beach while I *am doing* some pilates.
```

[image: Highlighted differences example]

Answer (score 1):

Use `difflib` to get the matching blocks:

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

s1 = "I'm enjoying the summer breeze on the beach while I do some pilates."
s2 = "I'm enjoying the summer breeze on the beach while I am doing some pilates."

x = SequenceMatcher(None, s1, s2)
m = x.get_matching_blocks()
```

[out]:

```
[Match(a=0, b=0, size=52),
 Match(a=52, b=55, size=2),
 Match(a=54, b=60, size=14),
 Match(a=68, b=74, size=0)]
```

Then, use color string to put the colors on the substrings:

```py
s2_new = ""
for m in x.get_matching_blocks():
    if m.b > i:
        s2_new += s2[i:m.b]
    s2_new += f"\033[91m{s2[m.b:m.b+m.size]}\033[0m"
    i = m.b + m.size
    
print(s2_new)
```

[out]:

```
\x1b[91mI'm enjoying the summer breeze on the beach while I \x1b[0mam \x1b[91mdo\x1b[0ming\x1b[91m some pilates.\x1b[0m\x1b[91m\x1b[0m
```

---

Alternatively, if you want less granularity than `get_matching_blocks()`, try:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

s1 = "I'm enjoying the summer breeze on the beach while I do some pilates."
s2 = "I'm enjoying the summer breeze on the beach while I am doing some pilates."

x = SequenceMatcher(None, s1, s2)

matches = []
a, b = 0, 0
while True:
    m = x.find_longest_match(alo=a, ahi=len(s1), blo=b, bhi=len(s2))
    a, b = m.a + m.size, m.b + m.size
    if m.size == 0:
        break
    else:
        matches.append(m)
        
print(matches)
```

[out]:

```
[Match(a=0, b=0, size=52), Match(a=54, b=60, size=14)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `difflib` [`matching_blocks`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks) method to isolate the matching substrings from the rest.

Here i made an example where I rebuild the words from scratch, but use `*` whenever the substring is outside the matches.

#### Code:

```py
import difflib as dl


def line_builder(blocks, sentence, a_or_b):
    new_sentence = ""
    position = 0
    for block in blocks:
        match_start = getattr(block, a_or_b)
        if block.size == 0:
            continue
        if match_start > position:
            new_sentence += f"*{sentence[position:match_start]}*"
        new_sentence += sentence[match_start: match_start + block.size]
        position = match_start + block.size
    return new_sentence


def print_diffs(a, b):
    s = dl.SequenceMatcher(a=a, b=b)
    m = s.get_matching_blocks()
    new_a = line_builder(m, a, "a")
    new_b = line_builder(m, b, "b")
    print(f"Here are the differences\n\t{new_a}\n\t{new_b}")
```

And here is what it looks like in action:

```
$ python -i text_diffs.py 
>>> print_diffs("This is the most fun I have ever had", "This was the most fun I could have ever had")
Here are the differences
    This *i*s the most fun I have ever had
    This *wa*s the most fun I *could *have ever had
>>>
```

Keep in mid this might not work in all examples, it was written rapidly, it may still need some fine tuning for edge cases.